# How to add views to window from and array of views

Tags: javascript, arrays, window, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to write a simple game but I'm stuck here. I want to display my "bullets" by adding them to the window every time someone clicks. however this does not work because I get an error saying bulletsArray(i) is not a property so it wont work. Any suggestions? Ideas? Thanks

```
bulletsArray = new Array();

window.addEventListener("click", spawnBullets);
function spawnBullets(){
    bulletsArray.push(Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor: "white",
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            left: shipGun.left,
            top: 600
            })
        );
        for(var i = 0; i < bulletsArray; i++){
            gameWindow.add(bulletsArray(i));
        }

};
```

Comment: `bulletsArray[i]` not `bulletsArray(i)`

Answer (score 2):

Basim, Your for loop contains syntax error. Change the loop as follows

```
    for(var i = 0; i < bulletsArray; i++){
        gameWindow.add(bulletsArray[i]);
    }
```